# intercept an inbound mail, process with php

Tags: php, mysql, email

I've built a form for customers to message our help desk. This message is stored in the MySQL database for logging and tracking.

I want our help desk to be able to reply to the email, but instead of the email going directly to the customer, I want it to hit my server first (so the reply can be logged and tracked in a thread) and then the server would forward it to the customer.

I've got Laravel 5 setup with Mandrill to do outbound emails currently.

The part that stumps me, is how can I have my help desk send an email to our domain (ie noreply@exmaple.com) and have PHP handle that request? Once I can get it in PHP, I can parse the info out of the subject line etc..

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: firstly i would recommend using an existing support-ticket management system rather than building your own.

Comment: then i would recommend not using an email client but have the agents log in to the support system for all correspondence,

Comment: and then i have two options if you really want to go ahead with this - email can be piped to a script ( see your mail server for how to do this) or you have php monitor one or more mail out boxes

Comment: Is this an answer in serial fashion ^ ?

Comment: i get paid by the comment :-)

Comment: ;)  well I for one endorse making your own "wheels".  What have you tried?  Are you aware of PHP's [imap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) functions?

Comment: i write this stuff, do it myself take a month, install something per-built take a day, seems like a no-brainier to me ;-)

Comment: well, I'd also like to learn by doing. I built the system so far (on laravel framework) but I enjoy learning as I go. The timeline on this isn't too tight.
Dragon: You said "see your mail server for how to do this", could you expand?